# how to catch any error in telegram bot?

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch, telegram-bot

I am wondering how to catch any possible error in telegram bot API.
because of when an error occurs, telegram sticks to it and does not answering another requests.
I want to get rid if any errors that may cause by bugs in my code,or web-services I am using or blocking the bot or...
how can I avoid from sticking to one request in telegram bot API with PHP?
I think what I need is something like bellow code but more general for any kind of error:

```
try {

    $telegram->sendMessage([
        'chat_id'                  => '<PERSONS_ID>',
        'text'                     => 'Here is some text',
    ]);
} catch (TelegramResponseException $e) {
    $errorData = $e->getResponseData();

    if ($errorData['ok'] === false) {
        $telegram->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => '<ADMINISTRATOR ID>',
            'text'    => 'There was an error for a user. ' . $errorData['error_code'] . ' ' . $errorData['description'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you at least show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy  did you bother reading my question or even telegram bot API? you linked telegram core API that is used for developing telegram client application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved the issue by a trick.I created another bot for error handling.
So I have a bot X and an error handling bot Y.
here the POST method I receive webhooks from telegram:

```
public function postWebhook(Request $request)

    { .....
        try
        { ....
         bot X token
         everything the bot want to do...
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) 
        {
             bot Y send me the probable problem in my code....
        }
        catch (Throwable $e)
        {
               bot Y send me the probable problem in telegram such 
               as blocking ,..
        }
```

now I prevent sticking in an error and bot works great. even I am notified if a part of my web service has problem or my code has a  mistake.